# SOAPUI Groovy - append list items to property

Tags: groovy, eval, soapui

I'm new SoapUi and Groovy;
Trying to set and update (test case level) 2 properties, each iteration, from response of previous step request (called below "Get Media List").
each iteration I need to append items from response, into the properties.

Here's the script:

```
def fullMediaNameList = context.expand( '${#TestCase#MediaNameList}' )
def currMediaNameList = context.expand( '${Get Media List#o_mediaNameList}' )
AppendItemsToPropertyList(fullMediaNameList, currMediaNameList,"MediaNameList")

def AppendItemsToPropertyList(fullListStr, currListStr, propToUpdate)
{
    def fullList = []
    if (fullListStr != null && fullListStr != "")
    {
        //cast to list
        fullList = Eval.me(fullListStr)

    }

    //specific list to append
    def currList = []

    if (currListStr != null && currListStr != "")
    {
        //cast to list
        currList = Eval.me(currListStr)

    }


fullList.addAll(fullList.size(), currList)
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( propToUpdate, fullList.toString() )
```

I call this method twice; once for property of media id, which working OK(!)
and other, property called MediaNameList, and it fails with the following error:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: HD @ line 1, column 21. [DMAX HD, RTL Nitro HD, ZDFNeo HD, Deutsches Wetter Fernsehen, Tele 5 HD, sixx HD, Sat.1 Gold, MTV, E! Entertainment, Disney Channel] ^ 1 error error at line: 8

Why is this? if I understand right it has issues with the string converting, and tried other commands instead of Eval.me and it didn't help.
e.g. `fullList = Arrays.asList(fullListStr)`
Other solution is welcome!
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you *think* you have a **List of Strings**, however they are unquoted, and so Groovy is trying to `Eval.me()` it as a **List of variables**. You are going to need something like:

```
def fullMediaNameList = context.expand( '${#TestCase#MediaNameList}' )
def fullList = []   // declare empty array
if (fullMediaNameList != null && fullMediaNameList != "") {

    //  break up the fullMediaNameList at commas, and itterate over the parts
    fullMediaNameList.split(',').each {

        // trim off leading or trailing whitespace from each part, and append as new element to the array
        fullList << it.trim()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked! with a small change using tokenize:

```
def fullList = []
if (fullListStr != null && fullListStr != "")
{
    //cast string to string list:
        //  break up the fullMediaNameList at commas, and itterate over the parts
        fullListStr.tokenize(',[]').each {
        // trim off leading or trailing whitespace from each part, and append as new element to the array
    fullList << it.trim()
        }
}
```

Thank you so much:)